# Custom CSV Uploader save to lookup field with name rather than ID

Tags: apex, visualforce, csv

I have put together a custom CSV uploader. I am uploading trees and one of the fields (Surgeon) is a lookup relationship to Contacts. Currently in order for it to work I need to have the ID of the contact in the CSV file but I need to make it work with the Name of the contact.

This is my controller:

```
public class importDataFromCSVController {
public Blob csvFileBody{get;set;}
public string csvAsString{get;set;}
public String[] csvFileLines{get;set;}
public List<Tree__c> treelist{get;set;}
public importDataFromCSVController(){
    csvFileLines = new String[]{};
    treelist = New List<Tree__c>();
}
public void importCSVFile(){
    try{
        csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
        csvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n');

        for(Integer i=1; i<csvFileLines.size();i++){
            Tree__c treeObj = new Tree__c();
            string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');
            treeObj.Type__c = csvRecordData[0];
            treeObj.Status__c = csvRecordData[1];
            treeObj.Geolocation__Latitude__s = Decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[2]);
            treeObj.Geolocation__Longitude__s = Decimal.valueOf(csvRecordData[3]);
            treeObj.Surgeon__c = csvRecordData[4];
            treeObj.Action__c = csvRecordData[5];

            treelist.add(treeObj);
        }
        insert treelist;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ApexPages.Message errorMessage = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'An error has occured');
        ApexPages.addMessage(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Lookups wont take data using the names. Their actual access can be possible through the Id only.

Comment: Can you do a SOQL query against the `Contact` object in the `importDataFromCSVController` class to get the Id?

Comment: If you have no chance of having duplicate names of contacts, then Keith has already answered your question, else let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code to accomplish what BarCotter suggest would look something like this:

```
// Get all the names
List<String> names = new List<String.();
for(Integer i=1; i<csvFileLines.size();i++){
    ... existing code
    // Replace this line
    treeObj.Surgeon__c = csvRecordData[4];
    // with this line
    names.add(csvRecordData[4]);
    ... existing code
}

// Query for the Contacts that have matching names
Map<String, Id> m = new Map<String, Id>();
for (Contact c : [
        select Id, Name
        from Contact
        where Name in :names
        order by CreatedDate desc
        ]) {
    m.put(c.Name, c.Id);
}

// Set the Contact Id for each name
for (Integer i = 0; i < treelist.size()) {
    Tree__c t = treelist.size[i];
    Id id = m.get(names[i]);
    if (id != null) {
        t.Surgeon__c = id;
    } else {
        // Throw an exception: no match for the name
    }
}
```

Comment: Contacts may have duplicate values, putting it in a map will store the last value inserted.

Comment: @SantanuHalder Sure. But it starts with the problem statement: if the CSV only has the name then there is no way to get the right Contact if there are duplicates. Perhaps you should offer an answer that watches out for duplicates?

Comment: @KeithC Fantastic, that is exactly what I needed! Thanks for the help